# Deleting data from SQLite Database is not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am working with SQLite and I am having trouble deleting data.
First and foremost, this is how I add data to the database:

```
public void addRecipe (QueryVars Recipee){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_Recipe, Recipee.getRecipe());

    db.insert(TABLE_Recipes, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

And this is how I get data from the database:

```
public List<QueryVars> getAllBooks() {
    List<QueryVars> recipes = new LinkedList<QueryVars>();

    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Recipes;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    QueryVars Recipe = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Recipe = new QueryVars();
            // Recipe.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            Recipe.setRecipe(cursor.getString(1));
            recipes.add(Recipe);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return recipes;
}
```

Saving and querying for data is working perfectly fine, but when I try to delete rows with the following code it just doesn't work.

```
public void deleteRecipes(QueryVars Recipe) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_Recipes, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(Recipe.getId()) });
    db.close();
}
```

This is the query I use to create the table:

```
private static final String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = 
        "CREATE TABLE Recipes ("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "Recipe TEXT"
        + ")";
```

And the constants I use in my code above are defined like this:

```
private static final TABLE_Recipes = "Recipes";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id"; 
private static final String KEY_Recipe = "Recipe"; 
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_Recipe};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code which could potentially be the source of the error, but both have the same cause: You are letting SQLite generate the ids of your `Recipe` objects but you are never setting that id to your objects.

1. When you add something to the database the `add()` method returns the id which was generated for that row. You can just set this id to the `Recipe` object otherwise that `Recipe` object won't have an id until you reload it from the database.

   ```
   public void addRecipe (QueryVars Recipee){
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(KEY_Recipe, Recipee.getRecipe());

       final long id = db.insert(TABLE_Recipes, null, values);
       Recipee.setId(id);

       db.close();
   }
   ```
2. When you are reading the `Recipe` objects from the database you are not setting the id value on the object, so no `Recipe` object you read from the database has an id which means you cannot delete them from the database. The fix is again pretty simple:

   ```
   public List<QueryVars> getAllBooks() {
       List<QueryVars> recipes = new LinkedList<QueryVars>();

       String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Recipes;

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

       final int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
       final int recipeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_Recipe);

       QueryVars Recipe = null;
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               Recipe = new QueryVars();
               Recipe.setId(cursor.getLong(idIndex));
               Recipe.setRecipe(cursor.getString(recipeIndex));
               recipes.add(Recipe);
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       return recipes;
   }
   ```

   This uses `getColumnIndex()` to reliably get the correct index of each column and then reads the id and the recipe from the cursor and sets them to the `Recipe` object.

---

**Please note** that your `Recipe` object needs to have a `long` id! `int` ids are not compatible with the `SQLiteDatabase`!

Answer (score 0):

You don't capture the database-generated id of your recipes and the id is zero. It doesn't match any rows in the delete.

Uncomment the

```
// Recipe.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
```

(consider using `cursor.getInt()` instead)

Possibly also store the return value of `insert()` as the recipe id.